# How to pass JSONObject through Async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having difficulty passing my JSON object in an Async thread to my main thread so that I can parse it there.  What is the best practice for this?  I tried changing the `String` of the onPostExecute to "JSONObject" but I get `can't be resolved to a type` errors.

Here is my code, I put an arrow at the JSONObject I need:

NewHomepage.java

```
public class NewHomepage extends Activity {

    public static String url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/android/SQL.php?username=";
    public static String usernamefromlogin;
    public static TextView errorchecking; 
    public static JSONArray user = null;

    //JSON Node Names 
    public String TAG_USER = "users";
    public String TAG_FIRST = "first";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);

          //get data from previous screen
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          getIntent().getExtras();

          //convert intent (intent) to string called "usernamefromlogin"         //error checking in log cat to see value of "usernamefromlogin"      
          usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2");         Log.d("log usernamefromlogin", usernamefromlogin);

          //take the string "url" and add string "usernamefromlogin" after it    //error checking in log cat to see value of url5
          String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);                           Log.d("log url5", url5);



          //start asynch task
          class PostTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();



               }//end PreExecute

               @Override
               protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               //pass url from outside class to inside this class   
               String url5 = params[0];

               //Creating new JSON Parser
               JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

               // Getting JSON from URL
--->           JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url5);




               return null;

               }//end doInBackground



               protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
               super.onProgressUpdate(values);


               }//end onProgressUpdate

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               super.onPostExecute(result);

               }//end onPostExecute
               }//end Async task

        //execute the Async task
        new PostTask2().execute(url5);












    }//end oncreate



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing on back press
    }

}//end class
```

Comment: `JSONObject.get("key")` is the method to get the values from the JSON based on the key

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  I just want to pass the JSONObject to my main thread, so that I can do the parsing there.  I already know how to get keys.

Comment: You can either use an Interface or since your AsyncTask class is an inner class, create an Object in the Base Class and then assign the value to it

Comment: your asynktask class is inside oncreate method. so you need to declare JSONObject as final in oncreate and you can then assign value you get from response to it in asynktask.

Comment: call a method in post execute method.

Answer (score 0):

From your doInBackgroung(), you should return like this -

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url5);
return json.toString();
```

then in your onPostExecute(), do this -

```
JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject(result);
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: I tried this, but, when I put that code in the `onPostExecute()` it asked me to surround with try/catch.  So I did that, now how do I get `newJson` to my main thread?

Comment: onPostExecute() runs in the main thread, you can update your UI from this method.